# Android NDK - Eclipse can't include jni.h

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk

So I'm using Eclipse 4.2 to build my projects which imports native functions in Java.
Everything build fine with eclipse and yesterday everything worked fine.

Today my eclipse stopped to resolve jni.h headers and others android header and shows me errors.
My project builds correctly but eclipse forbids me running application with message saying that there are errors in my application.

I have all paths to  symbols in project paths and symbols c,cpp.
And it was working without errors... My only solution right now is to build project, then restart eclipse and run application...

EDIT: oh... It's funny... Now eclipse doesn't start android emulator when i click run as...

EDIT2: even when I create new project...

EDIT3: Its funny... I had to add in avd device... I don't know how it is possible but for two days I've been using it without device in avd and it was working... (I haven't change api or anything like this and I haven't touch AVD Manager)

EDIT4: Strange things happenes in eclipse... I still don't know why eclipse has problems with includes...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a bug in ADT 20. Refer http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33788

Go with Alex' adwise until ADT 21 or a patch for ADT 20 is released.

[edit] BTW: you can always simply delete errors in the `Problem` list ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You can go to `Project|Properties|C/C++ General|Code Analysis` then uncheck everything in there. That will provide for running your app until you figure out the proper fix.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by choosing Properties for the project

Properties -> C/C++ General -> Preprocessor Include..-> Entries -> Setting Entries -> CDT User Setting Entries

Add -> Include Directory -> File System Path, and enter the path of the includes like:
${NDK_ROOT}\platforms\android-5\arch-arm\usr\include

Also I found that this working for me only if I checked "Contains system headers" checkbox.